# Having issues with creating Tile Sets in Xcode 8. Anyone have any success?

Tags: sprite-kit, tile, xcode8

Been trying to create a tile set to use in the new scene editor in the Xcode 8 beta. But, I drag a image in there from the asset catalog and  I click away and it's as if I never placed a texture in there. I can't figure out how to get the tiles to save the image data.

Before:
[image]

After I click away to any other file then click back:
[image: http://imgur.com/BucQ0Gk]

Then the Scene Editor won't let me select a tile to use to draw. 
Anyone had any luck saving image data in a tile and using it? 
Any workarounds? 
Anyone able to upload an Xcode project with a tile set that I can try to maybe modify?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After making the changes to the tile set simply press cmd + S (or click File -> save) before clicking away. Then the changes will persist